# Azure App Service - Always On vs Health Check

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring, azure-appservice

If I have one instance of app service is it still recommended to have enabled Health Check (e.g. for monitoring purpose)?
[image]

If yes then what about functionality Always On? Doesn't it double requests which at the end do the same thing? I mean to keep application running without idle and check if there are server http errors.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Azure WebApp Always On and Health Check features are used for different use-cases.

- Always On setting is used to keep the app always loaded. This eliminates longer load times after the app is idle. With the Always On feature, the front end loadbalancer sends a request to the application root.
- Health check setting allows you to monitor the health of your site using Azure Monitor where you can see the site's historical health status and create a new alert rule.

You can disable Always On and just use Health Checks, that will cover both use-cases:

- keep application running without idle
- monitor the health of your site

Comment: If Always On is disabled and AppService hosts a containerized app with HEALTHCHECK set, stay the app service running, or will be shutting down when no traffic?

Comment: Yes, what if the app is containerized? Will container registry try to restart the app?